# Select/Deselect All Button for shiny variable selection

Tags: r, shiny

I have this statement that lets me get basic descriptive statistics about my variables:

```
checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Columns in diamonds to show:',
                          names(input_data), selected = names(input_data))
```

However, after having to unclick 10 variables to get the one variable I was interested in, I realized that this user interface is not very friendly. I would like to add a button that selects/deselects all when you click it. It can be clicked multiple times. I am not even sure how to begin. Any nudges will help.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
hw<-diamonds 

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  title = 'Examples of DataTables',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Columns in diamonds to show:',
                           names(hw), selected = names(hw))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"), 
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel('hw', dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
        )
    )
  )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
data(diamonds)
hw<-diamonds  
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- hw[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
    summary(dataset)
  })
  # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
    library(ggplot2)
    hw[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
  })
})
```

Comment: Please provide the rest of your code - `server.R`, `ui.R`, and any data required to test your program.

Comment: hw was something else originally so I quickly put something together for the diamonds dataset.

Comment: Why not just use a `selectize(multiple = TRUE)` instead of your `checkboxGroupInput()`? You're also setting `selected =` to `names(...)` so that's why everything is selected - just make `selected = ''` to fix that.  This solution won't get you at the "All" option (which even I am looking for) but for ~10 selections I think it's the way to go here.  Could be wrong.

Answer (score 14):

This is how I set up a select/deselect all button.

In ui.R add an action button where needed:

```
actionButton("selectall", label="Select/Deselect all")
```

Then server.R uses updateCheckboxGroupInput based on the condition of the action button. If the number of times the button is pressed is even it will select all, else if it's odd it will select none.

```
# select/deselect all using action button

observe({
  if (input$selectall > 0) {
    if (input$selectall %% 2 == 0){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, 
                               inputId="show_vars",
                               choices = list("carat" = "carat",
                                              "cut" = "cut",
                                              "color" = "color",
                                              "clarity"= "clarity",
                                              "depth" = "depth",
                                              "table" = "table",
                                              "price" = "price",
                                              "x" = "x",
                                              "y" = "y",
                                              "z" = "z"),
                               selected = c(names(hw)))

    } else {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, 
                               inputId="show_vars",
                               choices = list("carat" = "carat",
                                              "cut" = "cut",
                                              "color" = "color",
                                              "clarity"= "clarity",
                                              "depth" = "depth",
                                              "table" = "table",
                                              "price" = "price",
                                              "x" = "x",
                                              "y" = "y",
                                              "z" = "z"),
                               selected = c())

    }}
})
```

The full app for your example below - you'd need to add session to the server function, I added a condition for renderDataTable when no variables are selected.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
hw <- diamonds

runApp(
  list(
    ui=(
      fluidPage(
        title = 'Examples of DataTables',
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("selectall", label="Select/Deselect all"),
            checkboxGroupInput('show_vars', 'Columns in diamonds to show:',
                               names(hw), selected = names(hw))

          ),
          mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
            tabsetPanel(
              id = 'dataset',
              tabPanel('hw', dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
            ))))),

    server = (function(input, output, session) {
      output$summary <- renderPrint({
        dataset <- hw[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
        summary(dataset)
      })
      observe({
        if (input$selectall > 0) {
          if (input$selectall %% 2 == 0){
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, inputId="show_vars",
                                     choices = list("carat" = "carat",
                                                    "cut" = "cut",
                                                    "color" = "color",
                                                    "clarity"= "clarity",
                                                    "depth" = "depth",
                                                    "table" = "table",
                                                    "price" = "price",
                                                    "x" = "x",
                                                    "y" = "y",
                                                    "z" = "z"),
                                     selected = c(names(hw)))

          }
          else {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, inputId="show_vars",
                                     choices = list("carat" = "carat",
                                                    "cut" = "cut",
                                                    "color" = "color",
                                                    "clarity"= "clarity",
                                                    "depth" = "depth",
                                                    "table" = "table",
                                                    "price" = "price",
                                                    "x" = "x",
                                                    "y" = "y",
                                                    "z" = "z"),
                                     selected = c())

          }}
      })

      # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
     output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
        if (is.null(input$show_vars)){
          data.frame("no variables selected" = c("no variables selected"))
        } else{
          hw[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
        }

      })
    })

  ))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed because I didn't want "all" or "none", but "some" as the default.

Comment: Not sure if something changed in `shiny`, but as of this comment `selected = ""` works to un-select everything and `selected = c()` does not

Answer (score 14):

The `shinyWidgets` library has a nice function called `pickerInput()` that comes with a "select all/deselect all" feature. After much research, I found this to be the only Shiny input that has this feature built-in:

[image]

Link to site: https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/index.html

Answer (score 10):

I added a `global.R` for loading packages and data - not always necessary but it's generally cleaner. There might be different ways to do what I did below, but I tend to use conditional panels in situations like this.

### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  title = 'Examples of DataTables',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      radioButtons(
        inputId="radio",
        label="Variable Selection Type:",
        choices=list(
          "All",
          "Manual Select"
        ),
        selected="All"),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.radio != 'All'",
        checkboxGroupInput(
          'show_vars', 
          'Columns in diamonds to show:',
          choices=names(hw), 
          selected = "carat"
        )
      )

    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"), 
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel('hw', dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
##
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  Data <- reactive({

    if(input$radio == "All"){
      hw
    } else {
      hw[,input$show_vars,drop=FALSE]
    }

  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    ## dataset <- hw[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
    dataset <- Data()
    summary(dataset)
  })

  # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
    Data()
    ## hw[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
  })
})
```

### global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
hw <- diamonds
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't what I had in mind but it gives me an idea to create a button called "Select All" that can then go to two conditional panels, one that has all of them selected and the other that is empty. Thanks for the inspiration!