# Shiny widgets check box groups activating on enter

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to design a search feature where you can search via a text input and through check boxes (I am using shinyWidgets), except for some reason, when you hit enter inside the text input it is activating my "ALL/NONE" button.

The goal is that when the ALL/NONE button is hit that it alternates between selecting all of the check boxes and selecting none of them. The issue is that hitting enter in the text box also seems to activate the observe, even when it should only be activating by the button.

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinyWidgets)


Habitat <- c("grass", "water", "stone")
ID <- c(1, 2, 3)

data <- data.frame(ID, Habitat)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      textInput("keyword_search", label = "Search by Keyword"),
      uiOutput("h_button"),
      uiOutput("habitat_filter")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(width = 10
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$habitat_filter <- renderUI({
    habitat_choices <- checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "habitat", label = "",
                                          choices = unique(data$Habitat[!is.na(data$Habitat)]),
                                          selected = unique(data$Habitat[!is.na(data$Habitat)]))
  })
  
  output$h_button <- renderUI({
    habitat_button <- checkboxGroupButtons(
      inputId = "habitat_switch",
      choices = "ALL / NONE",
      size = "sm",
      selected = "ALL / NONE")
  })
  
  observe({ #all/none button for habitats
    x <- input$habitat_switch
    if (!is.null(x)) {
      x <- unique(data$Habitat[!is.na(data$Habitat)])
    }
    else {
      x <- character(0)
    }
    
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session,
      "habitat",
      label = NULL,
      choices = unique(data$Habitat[!is.na(data$Habitat)]),
      selected = x
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Weirdly, this problem seems to go away if it is coded outside of the sidebarLayout. i.e. if the ui side looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      textInput("keyword_search", label = "Search by Keyword", width = '100%', placeholder = "Type here to search the archive..."),
      uiOutput("h_button"),
      uiOutput("habitat_filter")
)
```

Unfortunately, I need the sidebar so removing it isn't an option for fixing the problem. Does anyone have a solution to prevent these features from being connected? Or an explanation for why this happening?

Comment: Use `observeEvent` and maybe use `reactiveValues` to more easily store defaults?

Comment: I think this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916115/select-deselect-all-button-for-shiny-variable-selection but personally think you should have two options "all" or "none" instead of one button for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing my observe for the button with this seems to avoid the problem as suggested here: [Select/Deselect All Button for shiny variable selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916115/select-deselect-all-button-for-shiny-variable-selection)

```
observe({ #all/none button for habitats
  x <- unique(data$Habitat[!is.na(data$Habitat)])
  if (!is.null(input$habitat_switch) && input$habitat_switch >= 0) {
    if (input$habitat_switch %% 2 == 0) {
      x <- unique(data$Habitat[!is.na(data$Habitat)])
    }
    else {
      x <- character(0)
    }
  }

  updateCheckboxGroupInput(
    session,
    "habitat",
    label = NULL,
    choices = sort(unique(data$Habitat[!is.na(data$Habitat)])),
    selected = x
  )
})
```

Still no idea what caused this issue initially, but this work around seems good enough